# Having issue with router in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, navbar, router

I have a navigation bar like **Dashboard**, **Customers**, **Product** after user logs into the system. This is how I have set up my routes file.

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const router: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'admin',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'customer',
            component: CustomerComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'product',
            component: ProductComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardComponent
        }
    ]
},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

My **app.component.html** file as base file. Have not included app.component.ts file here, it contains export class and templateUrl

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My **admin-dashboard.component.ts** file

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-admin',
template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Start of the navigation bar -->
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
          <div class="customer-panel">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div><!-- End of the customer panel -->

    </div><!-- /end wrapper -->
`
 })
 export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {}
```

And here is the **navbar.component.html** file

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigate">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="customer" routerLinkActive="active">Customers</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="product" routerLinkActive="active">Products</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="user">User</a></li>
            <li><a href="product-transactions.html">Transactions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

So, what I have done is my app loads app.component.html file which contains **router-outlet**. Which then loads **admin.component.html** file and I have loaded the other navigation bar links as children of **admin.component.ts** file with **router-outlet** here as well. It is working well but **routerLinkActive** is not working as **Dashboard** link is always active here. So, is my route design fine? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include `routerLinkActiveOptions` for your dashboard link as below :

```
 <li><a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Dashboard</li>
```

Comment: Now, other links are active on active but the dashboard itself is not active.